# Unable to use rowcount and conditional split in same data flow task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, rowcount, conditional-split

In SSIS,I  want to split the data after lookup based on whether any no match record is found or not .IF no match record has atleast 1 row or count it should process certain action. I used row count and then conditional split for the same i..e used row count in conditional process but since row count always comes to 0 , it failed.

Please suggest how to do the same in SSIS.

[image]

Here is my package snapshot for the same which shows that rowcount and cosnitonal split used together.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the rowcount transformation is saved into the variable after the Data Flow Task is executed, so you benefit from this variable value within the same Data Flow Task.

Instead, I suggest using the Lookup `No Match output` in each Lookup transformation to manipulate Records that are not found and the `Match output` to manipulate Records Found